# Is there a quick fix to missing helper error with jsreport handlebars nodeJS

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

trying to use jsreports and jscore node packages to dynamically render a pdf. I get the "Missing helper: "importStylesheet" error. Can anyone help or have seen this?
[image: nodeapi error message]

I've tried updating my jscore version so far but that didn't work. Feel like it's something small that I'm missing.